# JsTree is not creating nodes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jstree

i have tried everything i could find to make this work, but i don't know what else to do. Here is my Code

controller.js

```
app.controller('easyController',['$scope','$http','Api', function ($scope,$http, Api) {
    $('#jstree').jstree();

    $('#jstree').jstree(
        {
            "core" : {

                "check_callback": true,
                }
        });     
    console.log($('#jstree').jstree("create_node",[ '#', "Haalo"]));
    console.log($('#jstree').jstree().create_node('#', "Hallo", 'last'));
    console.log($('#jstree').jstree('create_node', '#', { 'attr' : { 'id' : '1' } , 'text' : "Hallo"}, 'last'));
    console.log($('#jstree').jstree().create_node('#' , {'text':'new node', 'type':'valid_child'}));
    $("#jstree").jstree(true).create_node("#","root1"); 
}]);
```

view.html

```
<div id="jstree"> </div>
```

When i write the list elements into the div then its working, but i cant add nodes with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Do not instantiate the tree twice, and only create nodes AFTER the tree is ready. Try this:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    "core" : {
        "check_callback": true,
    }
}).on("ready.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $("#jstree").jstree(true).create_node("#","root1")
});
```